# em-synchrony not asynchronous for identical requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, thin, eventmachine

In a rails app I have an asynchronous method which only works asynchronously when the requests are differents.

In my controller I have this method :

```
require "em-synchrony/em-http"
def test

    EventMachine.synchrony do
      page = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new("http://127.0.0.1:8081/").get

      render :json => {result: page.response}
      request.env['async.callback'].call(response)
    end
    throw :async
end
```

in my page I call this method like this :

```
//Not asynchronous. :(
//The second request takes twice more time than the first one
$.get("/test");
$.get("/test");
```

However, to make the calls asynchronous, I need the requests to be differents like so :

```
//Asynchronous. :D
$.get("/test?a");
$.get("/test?b");
```

Why?
I would like my code to be always asynchronous. Even for identical requests. FYI I'm using the server Thin

Answer (score 1):

I found your question really interesting, because I'm going to implement my first Reactor-pattern based web server and of course I went through em-syncrony.

Have you tried also using `aget` instead of `get`?

```
page = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new("http://127.0.0.1:8081/").aget
```

Let me know if it makes any difference :)!